# How to fix 'File name too long' errors when using Snakemake

Tags: snakemake

When using Snakemake, I store the values for my variables as part of the filenames (ex. "processed/count_{project}.tsv"). Recently, I've started using R formulas with many covariates as a variable. Now I get an error because the the filename is too long for the operating system. Has anyone else run into this issue and have any suggestions? Is there a canonical Snakemake approach for this problem?

Comment: Which OS? I have run into this in Windows in the past (unrelated to snakemake). I would think it is an OS issue rather than having to do with snakemake. You may want to find ways to shorten filenames.

Comment: @JeeYem I get the error on both Mac (Mojave) and Linux OS. In short, my question is whether there is a canonical Snakemake way to shorten filenames. Obviously, I could hack something together to shorten the filenames but I want to see if anyone has a better approach

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't think it is a good idea to store information into the filename.
Rather, I would create a temp file in tabular or yaml format linking the file in question to covariates or other data. Then read this file in R or else to extract the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use paths instead since paths allowed to be longer.